# Bootstrap column offsetting

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying this without luck. I want to have 5 columns within bootstrap, each "2" width. I want to offset the second column so that there is a "2" offset between column one and two. What we end up with is this:

2 Width Pricing Table - 2 Width Space - 2 Width Pricing Table - 2 Width Pricing Table - 2 Width Pricing Table - 2 Width Pricing Table.

Here is my code: http://www.bootply.com/MxnvNuTU6Q

```
<div class="col-md-2">
   <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
         <h3 class="panel-title">
            Bronze
         </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
         <h1>
            $10<span class="subscript">/mo</span>
         </h1>
         <small>1 month FREE trial</small>
         <table class="table">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     1 Account
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="active">
                  <td>
                     1 Project
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     100K API Access
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="active">
                  <td>
                     100MB Storage
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     Custom Cloud Services
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="active">
                  <td>
                     Weekly Reports
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset2">
   <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
         <h3 class="panel-title">
            Bronze
         </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
         <h1>
            $10<span class="subscript">/mo</span>
         </h1>
         <small>1 month FREE trial</small>
         <table class="table">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     1 Account
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="active">
                  <td>
                     1 Project
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     100K API Access
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="active">
                  <td>
                     100MB Storage
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     Custom Cloud Services
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="active">
                  <td>
                     Weekly Reports
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
   <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
         <h3 class="panel-title">
            Bronze
         </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
         <h1>
            $10<span class="subscript">/mo</span>
         </h1>
         <small>1 month FREE trial</small>
         <table class="table">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     1 Account
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="active">
                  <td>
                     1 Project
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     100K API Access
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="active">
                  <td>
                     100MB Storage
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     Custom Cloud Services
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="active">
                  <td>
                     Weekly Reports
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
   <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
         <h3 class="panel-title">
            Bronze
         </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
         <h1>
            $10<span class="subscript">/mo</span>
         </h1>
         <small>1 month FREE trial</small>
         <table class="table">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     1 Account
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="active">
                  <td>
                     1 Project
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     100K API Access
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="active">
                  <td>
                     100MB Storage
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     Custom Cloud Services
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="active">
                  <td>
                     Weekly Reports
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
   <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
         <h3 class="panel-title">
            Bronze
         </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
         <h1>
            $10<span class="subscript">/mo</span>
         </h1>
         <small>1 month FREE trial</small>
         <table class="table">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     1 Account
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="active">
                  <td>
                     1 Project
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     100K API Access
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="active">
                  <td>
                     100MB Storage
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     Custom Cloud Services
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="active">
                  <td>
                     Weekly Reports
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

What have I done wrong, is `col-md-offset2` not the right class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`col-md-offset2`
should be 
`col-md-offset-2`

That should create a gap between the first and second columns.

Comment: Thank you very much, will mark as answered in a min when it allows me to